# Complex expression in where clause in Entity Framework in repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression, where-clause

I have got the following expression that works with mockup data - hereby not using Entity Framework:

```
 public static Expression<Func<Resource, bool>> FilterResourcesByUserCriteria(IEnumerable<FilterValue> filterValuesForUser)
    {
      Expression<Func<Resource, bool>> filter = (resource) =>
      // Get filter values for the current resource in the loop

     resource.ResourceFilterValues

     // Group filter values for user
    .GroupBy(filterValue => filterValue.FilterValue.FilterGroup.Id)

    // Each group must fulfill the following logic
    .All(filterGroup =>

    // For each filter group, only select the user values from the same group
    filterValuesForUser
    .Where(filterValueForUser => filterValueForUser.FilterGroup.Id == filterGroup.Key)
    .Select(filterValueForUser => filterValueForUser.FilterValue1)

     // Each group must at least one value in the sublist of filter values of the current user
    .Any(filterValueForUser => filterGroup
      .Select(resourceFilterValue => resourceFilterValue.FilterValue.FilterValue1)
      .Any(x => x == filterValueForUser))
 );
```

}

However, I get this famous exception when I try to insert this expression in the where clause of my repository method (using Entity Framework):

```
Unable to create a constant value of type. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

I suspect this has something to do with a parameter called filterValuesForUser, which is a collection of a complex (i.e. custom) type.

Is this behavior even possible in Entity Framework where I do a subquery that is not directly related to Entity Framework? What I want to achieve here is to query on a subset of a custom list for each group in the query.

Any solutions for this or other workarounds? I'd like to minimize the amount of database calls, preferrably limit it to just one.

Comment: -1 Far too many objects that are outside of the query. It is not obvious what is being captured. Show more code for context.

Comment: @Aron I don't think there are too many here, it's just this `filterValuesForUser` prepared somewhere outside, the code here is fairly enough I think.

Comment: @Hopeless It was really quite hard for me to figure out that `filterValuesForUser` is an `IEnumerable` that is being captured.

Comment: @Aron yes, it was also hard for me but after scanning carefully we can spot it.

Comment: Hi Aron, I can imagine that. I have updated the code excerpt. I believe the filterValuesForUser is causing the problem, as it is not directly related to the item in the expression but rather an external collection.

Comment: in fact in some cases you can use an external collection inside the LinqToEntity query, but as I remember in some previous version of EF, we  cannot do that. So you should also tell more about what version of EF you are using.

Comment: The error message you posted seems to miss some text? `Unable to create a constant value of type...`? the type it mentioned here is important.

Comment: This is the error message I get:Unable to create a constant value of type 'Dime.Scheduler.Models.FilterValue'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: @Hopeless the issue is that the OP is trying to capture a `FilterValue` in the Expression. The result is in effect, he is trying to capture an `IEnumerable<Tuple'2>` which SQL has no concept of (except in tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Aron's answer, I used the PredicateBuilder utility in the LinqKit assembly to generate 1 expression rather than multiple and separate expresssions. This also avoids doing multiple database calls.

Here is how you can achieve this (pseudo-code):

```
public IQueryable<Resource> GetResources()
{      
       MyContext ctx = new MyContext ();
       IEnumerable<Expression<Func<Resource, bool>>> queries =
            filterValuesForUser.GroupBy(x => x.FilterGroup)
            .Select(filter => SecurityFilters.FilterResourcesByUserCriteriaEF(filter.Select(y => y.FilterValue1)))
            .Select(filterExpression => { return filterExpression; });

   Expression<Func<Resource, bool>> query = PredicateBuilder.True<Resource>();
        foreach (Expression<Func<Resource, bool>> filter in queries)
        {
            query = query.And(filter);
        }

        return ctx.Resources.AsExpandable().Where(query);
}      


public static Expression<Func<Resource, bool>> FilterResourcesByUserCriteriaEF(IEnumerable<string> filterValuesForUser)
{
        // From the resource's filter values, check if there are any present in the user's filter values
        return (x) => x.ResourceFilterValues.Any(y => filterValuesForUser.Contains(y.FilterValue.FilterValue1));
}
```

I'm still having issues with getting this working in my repository but that has something do with something blocking AsExpandable() from working properly.

Answer (score 1):

The exact query you are asking for is impossible with LinqToEF (due to limitation of SQL). But fear not. It is possible to salvage your problem with a slight tweaking.

```
public static Expression<Func<Resource, bool>> FilterResourcesByUserCriteria(FilterValue filterValueForUser)
{
    //I assume you can write this part yourself.
}

public IQueryable<Resource> GetResources()
{
    IQueryable<Resource> resources = _context.Resources;
    IEnumerable<FilterValue> filterValuesForUser  = GetFilterValues();

    IEnumerable<IQueryable<Resource>> queries = from filter in filterValuesForUser
                                                let filterExp = FilterResourcesByUserCriteria(filter)
                                                select resources.Where(filterExp);
    return Enumerable.Aggregate(queries, (l, r) => Queryable.Concat(l, r));

}
```

Types and Extension methods expanded for clarity.

Comment: This is the right approach but the hardest part is actually what you assume the OP can write himself.

Comment: @Hopeless I agree. But the OP managed to get as far as he did on his Expression tree, so its not much of a leap to change that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. It will require some tweaking of my repository to get this working but it looks like the way to go.